# "The selected stored procedure or function returns no columns" when the query uses FREETEXTTABLE

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, full-text-search

I have the following stored procedure in an SQL Server database...

```
create procedure SupportTicketsFullTextSearch
@SearchText varchar(1000)
as
begin
  select ID, k.rank
  from SupportTicketsSummaries st
  inner join freetexttable(SupportTicketsSummaries, (ShortSummary, Description), @SearchText) as k on st.ID=k.[key]
  order by rank desc
end
```

I want to use this from Entity Framework, but when I try to add a function import, if I click the button to get the column information, I get the message "The selected stored procedure or function returns no columns"

I've done some searching, and seen a lot of people with the same problem, but they all seem to be using dynamic queries or temporary tables. My query doesn't use either (as far as I am aware anyway), and I can't find any advice that helps.

I tried adding...

```
SET FMTONLY OFF
```

...at the beginning of the SP, but it didn't help.

Anyone any ideas how I can import this SP as a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never found out why the import wizard couldn't see the schema, but it turned out to be really easy to fix.

All you need to do is open the model browser, right-click on the Complex Types node, and add a new complex type that has properties that match the columns returned by your stored procedure. Make sure the names match exactly.

Then start the function import wizard, choose complex type, and pick the one you just created from the drop-down list.

Hope this helps someone.